# With the find function, how do you find the last occurrence (not first occurrence) of a key with multimap on C++?

Tags: c++

I have a multimap set with multiple similar keys. It's sorted and I need to obtain the last occurrence of a value first.

Comment: Can you iterate from rbegin to rend? https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/rbegin/

Answer (score 3):

[`std::multimap::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range) finds the first element not less than the searched key and the first element greater than the searched key, if the key being searched for doesn't exist, they will be equal:

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <iterator>

std::multimap<int, int> mmap{{1,1}, {2,2}, {2,2}, {4,4}};
std::optional<decltype(mmap)::mapped_type> value{};
if(auto [first,last] = mmap.equal_range(key); first != last) {
    value = std::make_optional((std::prev(last, 1))->second);
}
if(value.has_value()) {
    //Do the Thing!
}
```

Comment: @Blastfurnace Made it better. Now the code doesn't crash on edge cases. Tested with `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5` as the key.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [`std::multimap::equal_range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/equal_range). This will give you a range of the values that match your key. You can then iterate to the final one to get what you are looking for.

ie. something like:

```
auto range = mymap.equal_range(mykey);
auto last = std::advance(range.first, 
                std::distance(range.first, range.second) - 1);
```

Make sure you check for errors like key doesn't exist etc. Also this code is untested.